# "Warning [ODEJoint.cc:1105] GetForceTorque: forgot to set <provide_feedback>?" with some models

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After recent drcsim changes, some of our custom models started spamming

```
Warning [ODEJoint.cc:1105] GetForceTorque: forgot to set <provide_feedback>?
```

to the terminal at really high frequency. Can anyone give me a hint why that happens? So far I´ve been unsuccessful in tracking this issue down, but it appears it can´t be that hard to solve. I´m uploading models for use with gazebo through the parameter server. The drcsim_gazebo launch files work fine, so I guess we do something differently (or wrong).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4722/%22warning-%5Bodejoint.cc:1105%5D-getforcetorque:-forgot-to-set-%3Cprovide_feedback%3E?%22-with-some-models/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 473 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok found it. Accidentally loaded gazebo transmission and other settings for some joint names that are not part of the model and missed setting them for some other joints.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0